# solr indexes documents but does not search in them

Tags: solr

I am a novice with Solr and i was trying the example that comes in the example folder of Solr(3.6) package(`apache-solr-3.6.0.tgz`). I started the server and posted the sample *xml* files in `example/exampledocs` and then i could search for stuff and Solr would return matches and it was all good. But then i tried posting another xml file with more than 10,000 documents. I modified the `example/solr/conf/schema.xml` file to add the fields of my xml file and then restarted the server and posted my xml file. I checked the statistics in Solr admin panel(`http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/stats.jsp`) and it shows `numDocs : 10020`. Now this means that the documents were successfully posted. But when i search for anything that was present in my posted documents(from the 10,000 document xml file),it returns 0 results. But Solr is still able to return results from searches that match content in the documents that come by default in the `example/exampledocs` folder. I am clueless about what has happened here. The value of `numDoc` clearly suggests that the documents i posted in the xml file were indexed. 
Anything else i can inspect to see what's wrong with this?

The schema which comes in the example with the Solr package is like this

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="sku" type="text_en_splitting_tight" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true"/>
<field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/><field name="alphaNameSort" type="alphaOnlySort" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<field name="manu" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true"/>
<field name="cat" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="features" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="includes" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true"/>
<field name="weight" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="price" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="popularity" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="subject" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="inStock" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

and more....

The schema of the xml file which i posted had some fields in common with the above schema like title,description,price,etc so i entered the rest of the fields in schema.xml like this

```
<field name="cid" type="int" indexed="false" stored="false"/>
<field name="discount" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="link" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="status" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="pubDate" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="image" type="string" indexed="false" stored="false"/>
```

Comment: What are your queries and schema like? Have you tried searching for `*:*`?

Comment: @MauricioScheffer i tried searching for `*:*` and the result tag's attribute `numfound` is `10020`. but it shows only 10 result `<docs>`. i queried for words in title or description,ill edit my question to show you the schema

Comment: @MauricioScheffer i queried for `*:*` and passed the parameter `start=50` and it shows me the data which i had posted in my xml file but why is it unable to search on them?

Comment: @lovesh: It's probably showing 10 results because the default row count is set to 10, you can directly edit the URL to increase/decrease this number.

Comment: @lovesh what's the query that has unexpected results?

Comment: @MauricioScheffer If i search for `Sony` which is present in `title` field of lot of documents then also it returns `numFound=0` in the `response`. I tried some other words which are present in `title` or `description` field but still `numFound=0`. I have made both the fields `indexed` and `stored` in schema.xml so it should search on them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the default settings from the Solr example site, then by virtue of the `df` setting in the solrconfig.xml file for the `/select` request handler, it is setting the default search field to the `text` field.

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
   <!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
        will be overridden by parameters in the request
    -->
   <lst name="defaults">
     <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
     <int name="rows">10</int>
     <str name="df">text</str>
   </lst>
  ....
 </requestHandler>
```

If you look in the schema.xml file just below the field definitions you will see the multiple `copyField` settings that are moving the values from certain fields into the `text` field and therefore making them searchable via the default field setting. In your example of searching for `Sony` in the title field, if you look at the copyField statements, you will see that the `title` field is not being copied to the `text` default search field. Therefore, the documents with the Sony title value are not being returned in your query.

I would suggest the following:

1. Try a query by specifying the following: `title:Sony` that should return what you are expecting.
2. If you want the `title` field to be included in the default query field, then add the following copyField statement to the schema.xml file and reload your 10000 document file.
    `<copyField source="title" dest="text">`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using `title:sony` works. But if i change `title`'s type from `text_general` to `text_en_splitting` the query `title:sony` again returns 0 results. Also if i set `name`'s type from `text_general` to `text_en_splitting` i dont get the desired behavior. i mean if the `name` field contains `A-DATA` and i search for `adata` nothing matches. Any ideas why these things happen?